# product_images PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql

### I'm working on a e-commerce site.

At this point I have:

-*table products*

-*table images*

-*table product_images* (because I want the product to have several images)

-my products are stored in the *table products*;

-my images are being uploaded to a folder named 'uploads' and stored in the *table images*;

Now, I don't know how to populate *table product_images*.
My table product_images has product_id_FK, image_id_FK and product_image_id. 
I don't know how to join.
What is the best way of relating two items of two different tables?
(And I don't know if this is the best way of adding a product with multiple images)

Comment: I think people might have down-voted your question, because if you search using google you can probably find an example of this in a few minutes. Have you read my answer, maybe search cross ref tables for a general example of what you need. Here's the 1st I found: http://www.developerdrive.com/2011/12/the-xref-table-for-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is the best way to have multiple images for products in your example.

Your table product images will be a cross reference table.
It should contain the id of the product (product_id) and the id of an image (image_id). 
This may be all the data you need in your cross ref table. Although you may want to include a unique auto increment key (product_image_id), but its not essential. If you do not use a product_image_id, my advice would be to make a composite unique key of product_id and image_id.

Then you will need to look at JOIN statements to be able to extract the products images.